# Non-divisibility and Addtion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given two sets of positive integers $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_j\}$, $N \nmid a_i$ and $M \nmid b_j$ for any $i$ and $j$.

I would like to know if it is possible to derive a possible value of $P$ from $M$ and $N$ directly, where $P \nmid (a_i+b_j)$ for any combinations of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: What is the condition for all these numbers?

Comment: If $a\ne -b$, then yes: for instance, by ignoring completey $N$ and $M$ and picking $P=\lvert a+b\rvert+1$. If $a=-b$, then no.

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí All numbers are positive integers.

Comment: This is not clear.  You just want some number which doesn't divide $a+b$?  Just take $a+b-1$.  Not sure $N,M$ have to do  with it.

Comment: I am sorry. My original question was wrong. I have edited it to provide the correct conditions.

Comment: Have you looked at examples? Never forget this: mathematics is an observational science. In the case of Number Theory, we watch the numbers, how they behave, and try to find explanations that improve our understanding.

Comment: If $P$ exceeds the sum of the maximums of the sets , it will not divide any element of the given form. Does $P$ really NOT depend on $M,N$ ?

Comment: @Peter No, it does not depend on $M$, $N$, but I want to know if there is an efficient way to derive a possible value of $P$ from $M$ and $N$ directly.